# DVD Drive Burner Not Working

Tags: dvd, burning

I'm attempting to burn Bodhi Linux to a blank DVD. It's a dual-layered DVD+R DL disc and my drive has burned to these discs before.

I know bodhi will fit on a regular DVD or a CD but all I have at the moment is the dual layered DVDs. The computer I'm putting bodhi on doesn't support booting from USB either.

When I try to write the bodhi iso to the DVD with xfburn, I get this error:

[image]

I was able to burn to these exact DVDs about a week ago, preparing a video compilation using devede and xfburn.

Using k3bm, I get an error saying "Failed To Write" and when using brasero (as a last attempt) I received the same error as with xfburn.

Answer (score 0):

The error reported by xfburn means that the drive or the
operating system became impatient when trying to write
the first 16 data blocks to the medium.

Hard to say which of the involved components causes this.
Most suspicous is the combination of media and drive.
The standard advise is to first try other media resp.
other media types. If this does not help, you will have
to try a different DVD burner drive.

Comment: SCSI specs have this error code: 4 47 00 SCSI PARITY ERROR.
So there is some suspicion towards ATA or SATA controllers and cabling. Since the error key is B and not 4, the computer side is somewhat more suspicious than the burner side.